# Error Placing on same page PHP

Tags: php

some of my code in addUser.php it pure html
addUser.php

```
<form action="process/addNewUser.php" method="POST" id="userForm">
<table width="79%" border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="1"
    class="tabcont">
    <tr>
        <td width="47%" align="right">Title:</td>
        <td width="53%">
            <select name="title"><option value='0'>- - select - -</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="47%" align="right">
        First Name:</td>
        <td width="53%"><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstName" class="required" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right">Middle Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="middlename" name="middleName" class="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Password:</td>
        <td><input name="password" value="" readonly="readonly"
            id="password" class="required" " /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="2">
            <input name="addNewUser" type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

addNewUser.php

Here i am doing validations and displaying error messages and if it is success sending him to another page.

But i want to show an error message on addUser.php instead of validations page. Please give me a sample code how i can do it.

Comment: I think you are talking about server side validations, because, I can find class="required" in your code. Are you using any framework ? If yes then mention it.

Comment: i am doing client side validations also using jquery validataions that's why the class is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
addNewUser.php
```

Add the message in the session

```
$_SESSION["ErrorMsg"]="Name already exists";
```

And in your addUser.php , you put the following code in the place you need to show the msg :

```
if($_SESSION["ErrorMsg"])
{
  echo $_SESSION["ErrorMsg"];
  $_SESSION["ErrorMsg"]="";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but one more thing actually i am smarty template inheritance. How can i set error message in body.